# How to partially save merge results?

Tags: merge, diff, clearcase

I'm now in the middle of 3-way merging using ClearCase "Diff Merge" tool, and I want to stop and do the rest tomorrow.

I'm afraid that my machine may halt or restarted, so I want to save the merge results I made so far.

The problem is that the "Save" button is disabled, and it seems that it will be enabled just after I resolve all conflicts.

On the other hand, if I try to close the tool, it warns me that there are unresolved merge points so I could not resume the merge later:

[image]

Is that possible somehow to save it right now even before I resolved all conflicts?

Thx

Answer (score 2):

Not that I know of: The [merge Windows control](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r1m2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.hlp.win.doc/topics/xmldiffmrg/mergecontrols.htm) allows you to go from unresolved merge to unresolved merge, but not to save a merge in progress.

What I usually do is (if we are talking about the merge of *one* file, merge in text mode):

- save the current resulting merge content (the fourth panel content)
- cancel the merge in progress

Then later:

- checkout a new version with the saved content (or used the checked out version and overwrite it with the saved content)
- merge to that new version (which already contains what I want to see from the part I resolved previously)

---

Note: if you know that all resulting merge conflicts should be resolved with root (1), ours (2) or "their" (3), you could click on "`Navigate > Resolve-and-Advance mode`", and quickly click on 1, 2 or 3.

Comment: Do you mean to checkin the new version (with the saved content) to the target version through the rebase /deliver activities? I'm concerned that I won't be able to undo rebase /delivery if necessary

Comment: @user1762109 right: checkout and overwrite the content, but not checkin: as long as you don't checkin, you will be able to cancel a deliver or rebase. A cancel starts with a global undo checkout.